# webkit-transform doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, sencha-touch-2, css-animations

I am trying to implement navigation drawer in my sencha touch app using [this](http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/) article. The animation explained in the article is done using webkit-transform. This works like charm on chrome on my desktop and android devices but it does not work on the iPad mini, not even on chrome. Here is my css:-

```
.slide{
-webkit-animation-duration: .200s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.275, 0.080, 0.425, 0.855);
}    
@-webkit-keyframes slideout {

from {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

to {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(250px,0,0);
};
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
from {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(250px,0,0);
}

to {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
};
}

.slide.out {
-webkit-animation-name: slideout;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(250px,0,0);
}

.slide.in {
-webkit-animation-name: slidein;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
}
```

Is this some issue specific with iOS or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the animation duration?

Comment: @TigranPetrossian yes I did specify animation duration. Updated question with the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just using "from" (=0%) and "to" (=100%) in your keyframes without defining any other steps (25%, 50% etc.) I don't see the actual benefit of using keyframes.
Especially because keyframes cause lots of lines of CSS. Keyframes in my opinion do only make sense if you want to define substeps.

For all other purposes, transitions shall be the solution of choice since they're only animating from the starting point to your target value: [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/ABHFz/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
}

.slide.in {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.slide.out {
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(250px,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This somehow works, although I forgot to add a line where we are actually setting a timing function for the slide animation (and that's why the keyframes?)
`.slide {
-webkit-animation-duration: .200s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.275, 0.080, 0.425, 0.855);
}`

I am still not sure why your solution works and not the original css and this problem is only with iOS devices. Original solution worked everywhere else.